# Arduino Fan Control: BJT vs MOSFET

Tags: arduino, mosfet, bjt, motor-controller, fan

I'm brainstorming an electronics project where an Arduino (ATMega32U4 chip) will control this [Noctua NF-A12X25 5V](https://noctua.at/en/nf-a12x25-5v) fan. I thinking of getting the 3-pin non-pwm version over the 4-pin pwm version and pwm the 5V signal to the motor instead. However, I'm not too sure whether to use a BJT or a Mosfest between the motor power line and the Arduino signal line. Below is a schematic of the two option I'm looking into:
[image]
[image]

Based on the specs of the fan, the motor will draw a max current of 0.35A so both the BJT and MOSFET should be able to handle it. But, I want the "transistor switch" to have as low of a voltage drop (i.e power consumption) as possible between the collector/drain and emitter/source when the motor is on. Thus, there should be more available power to the motor.

My electronics knowledge is still very limited and I looked at the datasheet for both the BJT and MOSFET. The [BJT datasheet](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/2N3903-D.PDF) had a On-characteristic Vce(sat) of 0.2-0.3V while the [MOSFET datasheet](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/NDS7002A-D.PDF) had different Vds values. This left me a bit confused.

**If someone can explain which option is the better one and why, that'd be great.**

Comment: Given the two options you have, the BJT will result in less voltage loss to your load.  That MOSFET has (typically) 1.2ohm resistance (with 10V  G-S --- You'll probably come in lower VGS than that so your resistance would be even higher...)   That would be 0.35A * 1.2 ohm = 0.42V.    The BJT loss will be 'fixed' at about 0.2V     However there are very affordable MOSFETs available with vanishingly small resistance (such as AP2306 which has about 35 m-ohm resistance - thats 0.035 ohms!!!)   Your voltage loss there would be about 0.35A* 0.035 =  12mV

Comment: Whoa !  You are using a small signal BJT for a power switch. Hmmmm maybe not a good idea. Spec for the Onsemi 2n3904 is rated at Collector current max of 0.20 amps and you say that your fan draws 0.35 amps !

Comment: @xstack thanks for pointing that out. For some reason, I saw the Ic notation as base current on the datasheet (stupid me).

Comment: @KyleB I'll take a look at the AP2306! One of my other concern is the Vgs. From what I know/assumes is that Vgs eats into the 5V of power supply. So if Vgs is say 3V, then there is only 2V going across the motor. If that's true, then the motor will be less slower.

Comment: If you had a bare brushed motor, then a suitable *power* FET (**yours is not suitable!!!**) would be a better idea.  But what you likely have is a brushless motor hiding behind a controller, so you shouldn't really try to externally PWM it but rather use a version with a PWM input.  You might get away with it, but if you think it detail about what would actually be happening, you'd be horrified.

Comment: @kuan  VGS does not subtract from your voltage rail.

Comment: @KyleB. Really? So there is no voltage drop across the MOSFET when it's on? If I remember correctly, a BJT usually has a 0.6-0.7V drop across the voltage rail and a darlington pair will have 1.4V drop.

Comment: @ChrisStratton oh I didn't think about that. I know for a fact there is some PCB under the fan casing near the motor. You saved me the pain of buying a non-pwm fan just have to return it later.

Comment: @kuan    BJT's are not MOSFET's   ;)     What's true for one is not necessarily true for the other.     Yes, really, with that MOSFET (or any MOSFET with a low drain resistance) you'll have effectively "no voltage drop" across the MOSFET.       I already did the math for you previously   ;)    With 35 milli-ohms drain resistance and 350mA drain current, the voltage loss is 0.35 * 0.035 = 12 milli-volts.  For real   ;)    (Pure co-incidence the dual "35's" here...)

Comment: BTW, note that my company uses those AP2306 by the MILLION.   And often as not, they're used to control motors that are operating in that same current range you're operating in or higher.      We do not experience excessive field failures, well trusted component.    It would be a good idea however to put a snubber diode across the motor to quench voltage spikes as you PWM it    (we usually use 1N5817)

Comment: Kuan. You may not appreciate the hard reality, but I am trying to teach you how to think, not just give you an answer..and I haven't even started you on aliasing effects of PWM on a fan with its own Hall effect controlled rising frequency  clocking and the damage you might cause switching the internal capacitors on a non-PWM fan.. Get the 4 wire fan or use linear control on 3 wire

Comment: @Kuan this question is loaded with false assumptions on > Can you PWM a non-PWM fan without damaging the internal capacitor  at an  accelerated rate.? What is the Rce vs RdsOn? vs $ vs control volage or current?

Comment: @KyleB It seems now that PWMing the power is not a viable option with the fan's onboard circuitry. But your knowledge and contribution is very helpful! I'll definitely keep it in mind for future projects and designs :D

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 Yeah my bad on the wordings of my questions. I should of clearly asked if PWMing the 3-Pin fan is a good idea or not. Now, I understand Rce and Rdson (the equivalent resistance value when the BJT/MOSFET is on) and it's role in determining the power consumption. Not sure what you meant by "vs $ vs".

Comment: RdsOn vs cost vs Vgs(th) vs Imax

Comment: Vgs DOES NOT subtract from motor voltage BUT Vds does. Vds = Ids x Rdson. | |  R2 is FAR FAR too low and is eating your drive current. 100k is OK. Really. R1 = V/I = (Varduino-Vbe)/(Ic/Beta) = say (5-0.6)/(0.350 / 100) ~~= 1k. Change with assumptions. || R4 also say 100k and R3 almost not needed. | 2n7002 is the classic 60 pound weakling. It sort of works but there are vastly vastly better FETs at hardly if any more cost. | As shown R3/R4 rurn 5V PWM to 3V at gate and FET is REALLY struggling. Drive at WELL ABOVE Vgsth. Also below Vgsmax but at 5V you are well below that.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon. Thanks for your input. This helps reinforce the information shared by others!

Answer (score 2):

My up-front advice is to use the 4-wire version. It is much easier to work with, and widely available nowadays in any form factor you want (especially a big 120mm one like you're proposing.) Because the chop rate is so high (25KHz or so) they don't have acoustic noise problems.

You should only consider 3-wire or 2-wire if your design has to be extremely low-cost.

**2 Wire**

If you use 2-wire, you can use low-side chop. I'd lean towards a pair of 2n7002's in parallel - that should be plenty for this fan. If you use a BJT you need to make sure that there is adequate base current when the PWM pin is high - not a given thing. Check the ATMega datasheet. Consider a 2N2222 instead of 2N3904.

**3-Wire**

If you use 3-wire (that is, one with a tach) there's a couple of issues:

- You cannot use low-side chop. This will mess up the tach signal. Use high-side chop (P-channel FET is easiest).
- Even with high-side chop, the fan voltage can't go completely off: it will need smoothing so the BLDC controller chip will still make the tach signal. Add a cap across the switch device; its value will depend on your PWM switch rate and how much control you want.

One more thing: with a brushless DC fan, the catch diode is not necessary.

Comment: I agree 4 wire is easier to work with but not necessarily cheaper overall. When I designed for 10k units with twin 1U high fans  18 yrs ago cheapest solution was 2 wire Nidec fans and $2 LDO linear speed + thermistor auto speed control at 45~50'C XFRM temp

Comment: It isn’t the cheapest to use 4 wire. But this kind of fan is common enough now that it is not outrageously expensive either. It’s the standard type for a PC chassis (except those are 12V) so there’s economy of scale. Especially for the 120mm size.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The 4-pin is the direction I'll be heading towards now. The 2 and 3 pin does not seem worth the headache for my skill level. One thing I did read is that the Arduino PWM frequency is 490Hz.  Wikipedia said frequency under 22KHz might cause audible coil whine. I know there is a way to increase the Arduino PWM frequency. From the initial looks of it, it does not look fun.

Answer (score 0):

Let's Get back to basics using Ohm's Law. Then you can decide for yourself.

Using impedance ratio of switch to load and understand that the resistance goes down with bulk power rating of device.  SMT parts have the advantage for lower cost, size and resistance in FETs but tend to cost more.  For BJT type switches it demands a ratio closer to  Ic/Ib=10 to achieve rated Vce(sat) but you can compute the saturated resistance and now compare it to load R for voltage drop =I*R as both the BJT and the Fan type motors (BLDC+Hall sense+Cct) behave more like linear R.'s The fan load makes the BLDC incremental impedance look nearly constant in the steady-state above stall speed. But acceleration lowers impedance.

All you need is a low loss switch where the switch resistance is say < 2% of your load or better  for efficiency. (e.g. 10% loss poor but works, 1% or better is excellent)

*Remember, Pd loss and chip size are inversely proportional to R in BJT's , but your **cost, reliability and temp rise** are the important specs. with features.*  FETs are a wiser power choice here, but cost depends on wise choices is far better in SMT.

Load = 5V x 0.35A = 1.75W or 5/0.35A = 14.3 Ohms on avg.
Thus you want a switch <  280 mOhm (2%)

Transistor switches are based on Ic/Ib=10 for  Vce(sat) @ ___ A.

*The BJT effective switch resistance is usually inverse to its Pmax rating (with heatsink) :*

- for  Vce(sat) max @ Ic in the datasheet, the Collector-emitter bulk resistance is defined as follows:

### Rce=Vce(sat)/Ic

For the 2N3904 under-rated at 200mA , Rce = 0.3Vmax/50mA = 6 Ohms
A power transistor with a current rating of >= tbd Amps

e.g. PN2222A — NPN General-Purpose Amplifier
Vce(sat) = 300mV @ 150mA = 2 Ohms &  1V @ 500mA = **2 ohms**   (No good).

So how does **Rce** vary with power ratings on a transistor?  Examples to follow:

[KSC2328AYBU](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/KSC2328A-D.pdf)    TRANS NPN 30V 2A TO-92L  **1000 mW**  Rce= 2Vmax /1.5A = **1.3 Ohms** (no good)

[MJE243G](https://www.semicon.sanken-ele.co.jp/sk_content/2sc4511_ds_en.pdf)    TRANS NPN 100V 4A TO225AA  **15W max** Rce= 300mV max  @ 500mA = **0.6 Ohms** ( closer ...)

2SC4511     TRANS NPN 80V 6A TO220F  **30W max**  Rce = 0.5V max @ 2A = 250 mOhm  (Good) $2.46 (1pc)

It may be more cost-effective to choose an SMD FET of ~ 100 mOhm @ 4.5V or less... if you can use SMD ...

[RTR025N03HZGTL](https://www.semicon.sanken-ele.co.jp/sk_content/2sc4511_ds_en.pdf)  NCH 30V 2.5A SMALL SIGNAL MOSFET   **$0.79 Digikey (1pc)**
Rds On (Max) @ Id, Vgs
**92mOhm @ 2.5A, 4.5V  Best bet**  or equivalent Nch FET **rated at 4.5V or less**

### Summary

for Ic/Ib=10 in BJT's
2N3904 = 6 Ohms
PN2222A = 2 Ohms
KSC2328AYBU = 0.6 Ohms
2SC4511  = 0.25 Ohms

FET ($0.79 1pc) RTR025N03HZGTL = 0.1 Ohms @ 4.5V
**They can put FETs inside 4 wire fans much cheaper in volume than you.**

All Engineering choices can be **make vs buy** at every level of design and component level.

Comment: Thanks on the 2% rule of thumb Tony. I'll keep that in mind for future project. I drew the schematics myself in a quick rush based on my limited knowledge.

Comment: It would be better to find out more on the fans what they can tolerate. Last Time a design a thermal fan controller for Avaya, PWM interfered with my 1U muffin fans , so I made a linear control. You can also use 10'C junction temp rise for a starting spec  instead of 2% loss , but it comes down to cost andreliability in the end